# Where should I ask Questions about Cybercrime and Cyberlaws

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

On which site of the Stack Exchange network should I ask questions about cyberlaws, cybercrimes, etc., where mostly cybersecurity experts will respond to my question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends on the question.

If you want to know the technical details of cybercrime and cybercrime prevention, then [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com) is the place to go. Be sure that your question is specific enough. "How do I defend against vulnerability CVE...." is on-topic; "how do I secure my website" is not. (Although they do have a few canonical questions about securing your assets and incident response, simply because these things get asked so often.)

If you are interested in the legal aspects, then [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com) is the right site. Note however, that Law SE does **not** offer legal help. If you are the victim of cybercrime and need legal help, you'll have to hire a legal professional.
If, on the other hand, your question is more generally about clarification of the law, the question should be on-topic there.

As always, check if your question hasn't been asked there already; and if it is a new question, be sure you follow the guidelines in the Help Center of these respective sites.